# Unable to change author name in an ebook on iPad

Tags: ipad, books, metadata, epub

I have a Mac computer where I downloaded an ePub and then changed the author on the Mac in the list view of iBooks.

- MacOS 10.12.6 Sierra
- iOS 12.3.1 for the iPad

Then I dragged and dropped the ePub from iBooks to desktop. Then I airdropped the ePub to my iPad from my MacBook. The author name is showing accurate on my MacBook. I had the book transferred to my iPad and there it is showing the old name for the author. Deleting the book and re-downloading/re-editing didn’t help.

Apple Books on iPad is remembering the old metadata and not updating the author name.

I have been trying to fix this problem for the whole night but nothing worked. I even deleted Apple Books from my iPad and reinstalled it but that too didn’t work. I need to organize my files and this issue is really frustrating.

Can anyone help point out how I might make a change to the author data of an eBook I didn't author initially?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you add the ebook to your library on the Mac once you make the edit to the metadata there? Also, if you can tell us how you got the ebook and what tool you used to edit the file - perhaps we’ll have some ideas other than try again to delete and re-add.

Comment: Thanks for responding @bmike. Let me explain what I did: I downloaded the ePub and opened it in iBooks on my MacBook. In the list view of iBooks i changed the author name from Kaplan to Manhattan. Then, from the collections tab I dragged and dropped the book to my desktop and from there I airdropped it to my iPad. But it is still showing Kaplan in my iPad. Previously, editing the metadata in the list view and transferring books to my iPad has worked seamlessly. I’m stuck with just this one book now. Could you possibly solve my problem?

Comment: Let's get that into the body. Great details. I'll try to reproduce this when I'm off iOS and on macOS. The key info is you're using iBooks on Mojave ?? or another macOS to change the author? Click edit above and just make the post read correctly all through to cover the essentials before the final question is asked.

Comment: Edited the post above to add the accurate versions of MacOS and iOS.

Comment: Thanks bmike for taking the time out to respond. I’ve solved my problem and just now posted it as an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

After hours of frustration, I finally found a solution to my problem by doing the following:

1. Open Finder.
2. Click Go in the Finders menu and select Go to Folder.
3. Type ~/Library/Caches in the window currently displayed and click Go.
4. Locate the iBooks file and move it to trash.
5. Airdrop the same ePub file to iPad.

Following these steps I was able to see the accurate and updated author name on my iPad.

Comment: When you use the built in sync feature instead of managing files yourself it also works